# MongoDb - find a record based on _id using .aggregate() , $expr and $eq

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am writing a generic query builder tool of sorts and I am trying to find a record based on ID.
I am unable to do so.

The solution must use the following three:

1. .aggregate()
2. $expr
3. $eq

Why? Because I am building a generic query builder of sorts.
The following structure works fine as long as I am not dealing with _Id but when it comes to _Id it fails.

```
"$expr": {
                    "$eq": ["$_id", Object("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96")]
         }
```

**Doesn't work:**

```
db.persons.aggregate( [{
"$match": {
    "$or": [{
        "_id": ObjectId("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96")
    }]
}
}])
```

**Works:**

```
db.persons.aggregate( [{
"$match": {
    "$or": [{
        "_id": "ObjectId("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96")"
    }]
}
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are list of options,

- direct match - [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wVRmyvwLOkU)

```
db.persons.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { _id: ObjectId("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96") }
  }
])
```

- match using `$eq` - [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JgRpwA5J3-S)

```
db.persons.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: { $eq: ObjectId("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96") }
    }
  }
])
```

- match using `$or` - [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9MMIyyIC7C6)

```
db.persons.aggregate([
  { 
    $match: { 
      $or: [{ _id: ObjectId("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96") }] 
    } 
  }
])
```

- match using `$or` and `$eq` - [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kTTRu0ZtfuD)

```
db.persons.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [{ _id: { $eq: ObjectId("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96") } }]
    }
  }
])
```

- match using `$expr`, `$or` and `$eq` - [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uNv3YEmYkeS)

```
db.persons.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $or: [{ $eq: ["$_id", ObjectId("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2c96")] }]
      }
    }
  }
])
```